# Using DDE registered file associations with CDialog app?

Tags: mfc, file-association, cdialog

I know that SDI and MDI projects by design have the concept of a file type and that you can double-click from file explorer. For example:

```
BOOL CCommunityTalksApp::InitInstance()
{
    // Enable DDE Execute open
    EnableShellOpen();
    RegisterShellFileTypes(TRUE);

    // Process command line arguments (standard shell commands, DDE, file open)
    if (cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand == CCommandLineInfo::FileNew)
        cmdInfo.m_nShellCommand = CCommandLineInfo::FileNothing ;

    // Dispatch commands specified on the command line
    if ( !ProcessShellCommand( cmdInfo ) )
        return FALSE;
}
```

But I have a `CDialog` project which has two editors. Assuming that my installer has registered the two needed file type associations how do then get my `CDialog` based app to detect the file that was opened and direct it to the relevant editor?

Is this done in `InitInstance`?

In short:

- Did the user double-click a file?
- Was it a SRR or MWB file?
- Then post / cache a message to the `m_pMainDlg` for it to open the stated file in the appropriate editor.

How do I do the first two bullet points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this done in `InitInstance`?

Yes, you can use `ParseCommandLine` or handle `m_lpCmdLine` directly.

> Did the user double-click a file?

Does it really matter? That is more complicated to tell. If the app was launched by (say) ABC association, it could be that the user double-clicked an ABC file, but it could also be that they ran a batch file which did a `start somefile.ABC`, or anything else that eventually resolved to a `ShellExecute[Ex]` with an ABC file.

> Was it a SRR or MWB file?

Assuming those are the registered extensions, they would be part of the complete filename (name + extension) received in `m_lpCmdLine`. For a single file, the filename would also be in `CCommandLineInfo::m_strFileName` if `CWinApp::ParseCommandLine` was called.

> Then post / cache a message to the m_pMainDlg for it to open the stated file in the appropriate editor.

From `InitInstance` you would normally pass the filename(s) to the constructor of the dialog, and the dialog itself would later post the message at the end of `OnInitDialog` once everything is in place.